# Removing duplicate numbers from the parameter list and then update it

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to remove any numbers which are repeated in the parameter list. I tried doing this but it doesn't seems to work. Any help is appreciated!! thanks so much

#Im not allowed to use set()

Here's my attempted code:

```
def remove_all_repeats(numbers_list):
    a_list = []
    for num in numbers_list:
        if num not in a_list:
            a_list.append(num)

    numbers_list = a_list


numbers = [3, 71, 71, 3, 99, 3, 67, 88]
remove_all_repeats(numbers)
print(numbers)
```

Comment: you can use dictionary  though, eg `number_list  =Counter(number_list).keys()` in current code add return statement

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. Note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. We need a clear *question* - "Any help is appreciated!!" [does not qualify](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236) - and a clear *description of the problem* ("doesn't seem to work" isn't helpful - of course it doesn't seem to work, or you wouldn't be asking). *What happens* when you try using the code? What *should happen* instead, and *how is that different*? What is your *understanding of* the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Your function is correct, but numbers_list inside the function becomes a new local variable when you reassign its value to a_list.  It is not modifying the numbers variable that you define outside the function.  You have to return the value from the function like this:

```
def remove_all_repeats(numbers_list):
    a_list = []
    for num in numbers_list:
        if num not in a_list:
            a_list.append(num)

    numbers_list = a_list
    return numbers_list


numbers = [3, 71, 71, 3, 99, 3, 67, 88]
print(remove_all_repeats(numbers))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Unfortunately I tried this but it still doesn't work :( 

as my test case is like this:

```
numbers = [3, 71, 71, 3, 99, 3, 67, 88]
remove_all_repeats(numbers)
print(numbers)
```

Comment: then you have to reassign numbers -> `numbers = remove_all_repeats(numbers)`

Answer (score 2):

The function doesn't work because `numbers_list = a_list` is basically just reference to `a_list` and the list that is previously referenced by `numbers_list` doesn't change. To fix the issue, you can have the function return the updated list and assign the returned value to the `numbers` list

```
def remove_all_repeats(numbers_list):
    a_list = []
    for num in numbers_list:
        if num not in a_list:
            a_list.append(num)

    return a_list

numbers = [3, 71, 71, 3, 99, 3, 67, 88]
numbers = remove_all_repeats(numbers)
print(numbers)
```

Alternatively, you can also update the `numbers_list` inside the function using the expression `numbers_list[:] = a_list`

```
def remove_all_repeats(numbers_list):
    a_list = []
    for num in numbers_list:
        if num not in a_list:
            a_list.append(num)

    numbers_list[:] = a_list

numbers = [3, 71, 71, 3, 99, 3, 67, 88]
remove_all_repeats(numbers)
print(numbers)
```

Comment: This `if num not in a_list` is not efficient - if the list is huge.

Comment: @DanielHao Yes, I think replacing `a_list` with set or dictionary can be useful in making look up complexity to O(1) but OP mentioned it is not allowed

Answer (score 2):

since you are passing the list object and want to modify that list only then you can make a new list with unique element and use `list.copy` or `list[:]` to copy element of that list to your existing list.

```
def remove_all_repeats(numbers_list):
    a_list = []
    for num in numbers_list:
        if num not in a_list:
            a_list.append(num)

    numbers_list[:] = a_list
```

Comment: omg thanks!!! T_T  This method did not come through my mind at all. You saved my day :D

Answer (score 2):

many ways to do this; you can simply create a dictionary using the elements as keys and transform it back to list. This will remove duplicates.

```
numbers = [3, 71, 71, 3, 99, 3, 67, 88]
numbers = list(dict.fromkeys(numbers))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately as we havent learnt it in the course yet so we are not allowed to use this method as well :(